# Can't import submodule (Pycharm)

Tags: python, module, pycharm, git-submodules

I have successfully imported module `project` however I cannot import submodule `project.subproject`. I get the following message:

```
import project
import project.subproject

# Function call:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-b2298292e4a2>", line 1, in <module>
    import project.subproject
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.subproject'
```

Comment: Well, the obvious explanation would be that `project.subproject` really doesn't exist.  You haven't shown us your file structure, so we have no idea if this even **should** work.